# Hide elements that are in an array | jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Is it possible to hide elements that are in an array, e.g.

```
var elements = ['.div-1', '.div-3'];
```

With a structure of:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="div-1"></div>
    <div class="div-2"></div>
    <div class="div-3"></div>
</div>
```

So `div-2` should stay visible, while the elements that are in the array would be hidden by `fadeOut`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use that array as a selector by using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), for example:

```
$(elements.join(', ')).fadeOut();
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mCsQP/2/). By calling `.join(', ')` you're using the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) by turning it into the string `".div-1, .div-3"` and calling `.fadeOut()` on *those* elements.